# d3.js v4 timeParse() not working?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, date-parsing

I saw a lot of examples doing the same, but the `d3.timeParse()` function just doesn't work as expected in my code and returns `null`.

```
let parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

let now = new Date();

console.log(now)//returns js date object

let parsedNow = parseDate(now);

console.log(parsedNow) //returns null
```

See [this fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/L7hyqbfs/) for running example.

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to parse a date object which is incorrect, I think you want to format a date object into *"%Y-%m-%d"*

so instead of this

```
let parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");//timeParse is incorrect
```

it should have been

```
let parseDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");//timeFormat a date object into %Y-%m-%d
```

working code [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/L7hyqbfs/1/)